# How to check: Many values ​for one "name"

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I'm working on creating a school library for the project. I am new to the ASP.NET MVC environment. My problem is that I need to display authors for each of the books. Three models have been published: Books, Authors, Creators. In the Authors model reference is made to the Books and Creator tables. I stopped at the moment when I have to display all the creators of a given book. How do I display the title of a book with multiple authors? Can you give me some advice on how I could do it?

Autorzy Model

```
namespace WSzkola5.Models
{
    public class Autorzy
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Ksiazka Ksiazka { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Książka")]
        public int KsiazkaId { get; set; }

        public Tworca Tworca { get; set; }
        public int TworcaId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Ksiazka Model

```
namespace WSzkola5.Models
{
    public class Ksiazka
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Tytuł jest wymagany.")]
        [Display(Name = "Tytuł:")]
        [MaxLength(255, ErrorMessage = "Tytuł jest zbyt długa nazwa.")]
        public string Tytul { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "UKD jest wymagany.")]
        [Display(Name = "UKD:")]
        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "UKD jest zbyt długi.")]
        public string UKD { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Opis jest wymagany.")]
        [Display(Name = "Opis:")]
        public string Opis { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Tworca Model

```
namespace WSzkola5.Models
{
    public class Tworca
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Imię jest wymagane.")]
        [Display(Name = "Imię:")]
        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Zbyt długa nazwa.")]
        public string Imie { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nazwisko jest wymagane.")]
        [Display(Name = "Nazwisko:")]
        [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Zbyt długa nazwa.")]
        public string Nazwisko { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Autorzy Controller - Index Action

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var autorzy = _context.Autorzys.Include(c => c.Ksiazka).Include(c => c.Tworca).ToList();
            return View(autorzy);
        }
```

Autorzy View - Index

```
@model IEnumerable<WSzkola5.Models.Autorzy>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Książki</h2>
@if (!Model.Any())
{
    <p>
        Brak.
    </p>
}
else
{<table class="table table-condensed">
    <thead>
    <th>Książki</th>
    <th>UKD</th>
    <th>Autor</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var autorzy in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@autorzy.Ksiazka.Tytul</td>
                <td>@autorzy.Ksiazka.UKD</td>
                <td>@autorzy.Tworca.Imie @autorzy.Tworca.Nazwisko </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
}
```

And ViewModel

```
namespace WSzkola5.ViewModel
{
    public class AutorzyViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Tworca> Tworcas { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Ksiazka> Ksiazkas { get; set; }
        public Autorzy Autorzy { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your model it's not so easy to traverse through books as for now the loop:

```
@foreach (var autorzy in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@autorzy.Ksiazka.Tytul</td>
        <td>@autorzy.Ksiazka.UKD</td>
        <td>@autorzy.Tworca.Imie @autorzy.Tworca.Nazwisko </td>
    </tr>
}
```

would iterate over authors and if book has many authors then it would appear several times (one for each author) on the list. Whether it's your goal or not I'm not sure. Anyway, in order to list all authors of the book you would have to aggregate them like this:

```
@foreach (var autorzy in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@autorzy.Ksiazka.Tytul</td>
        <td>@autorzy.Ksiazka.UKD</td>
        <td>
            @foreach (var a in Model.Where(au => au.Ksiazka.UKD == autorzy.Ksiazka.UKD) )
            {
                @a.Tworca.Imie @a.Tworca.Nazwisko <br/>
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

But personally I'd changed the model so that Book has a list of its authors and then iterate over books.